# Weird in my UIImagePickerController with camera

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I met a problem on using camera by scratch on iphone. Other people's code just run fine on my 3GS, but my code doesn't.

When I implemented a `UIViewController` controller, and I add the following code in `viewdidload`:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.source = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self; //Previously added all the delegate properly
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Nothing comes out.
I checked in the debugger, it shows that the picker is allocated, but here is the major difference between my and success one.

```
picker._imagepickerflag.visible = 0;  //others show 1;
picker.UINavigationController._containerView: 0x0 ;  // others have value.
```

Can anyone help me on this, is there something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

Above code is wrong. It should be

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

This below is also wrong.

```
picker.source = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

it should be

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

And you should release it once it has been presented.

```
[picker release];
```

Hope that helps.